# Finding a string in a text file JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Okay, So I want to find a book in my file but for some reason every time I look for a book that's not in the file it returns it found the book. I already tried "try" and "catch" both come out with errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help, please!

```
public static void sbook (String filename){
    String[] blist = readBooks(filename);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter book you want to search: ");
    String book = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner = new Scanner(book);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String search = scanner.nextLine();
        
        if (!search.contains(book)) {
            System.out.println("The book is not present in the file");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("I found " + book);
        }
    }
    writeBooks(blist,filename);
    System.out.printf("Books are : \n%s\n\n",Arrays.toString(books));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanner = new Scanner(book);` will scan the `book` *string* for values, so `String search = scanner.nextLine();` will always be equal to `book`.

There are two options how you can fix it:

1. If you want to **look up the book in `blist` array**, you may want to use `contains` method of `java.util.List` like this:

```
boolean bookInArray = Arrays.asList(blist).contains(book);

System.out.println(
    bookInArray ? "I found " + book : "The book is not present in the file"
);
```

2. If you want to **use `book` as a filename**, you should pass a `java.io.File` argument to scanner:

```
// try-with-resources will close your scanner automatically after executing try block
try (Scanner bookScanner = new Scanner(new File(book))) {
    while (bookScanner.hasNext()) {
        String search = bookScanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println(!search.contains(book)
            ? "I found " + book
            : "The book is not present in the file"
        );
    }
}
```